# Best way to take input for a graph Data Structure in C?

Tags: c, data-structures, graph, input, user-input

I am working on a basic graph implementation(Adj List based) in C so that I can re-use the basic structure to solve all graph related problems.

To map a graph I draw on a paper,I want the best and easiest way. 
Talking of the way I take the input rather then how should I go about implementing it! :)

Should I make an input routine which asks for all the nodes label first and then asks for what all edges are to be connected based on two labels?

What could be a good and quick way out? I want an easy way out which lets me spend less amount of energy on the "Input".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best is to go for input of an edge list,

that is triplets of,

*Source, Destination, Cost*

This routine can be used to fill Adj List and Adj Matrix.

With the latter, you would need to properly initialize the Matrix though and setup a convention to determine non existent edges.

Comment: For the source,destination,cost triplet to work, we need to have the nodes in memory right?

Comment: You can keep them anywhere, even in database.

Answer (score 2):

Here you find details about representation of graph:
[Graph-internal-representaion](http://www.algolist.net/Data_structures/Graph/Internal_representation)
However here some codes in c++ and java are also given,which you can easily convert to C codes.